# looping through record set an updating individual records with calculated value

Tags: php

I have created a recordset which brings up 3 records. for each record I am trying to update a prorata value. the calculation works but only the first record is updated. I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

```
$results8a = mysql_query("SELECT orders.id, orders.install_date, orders_detail.product_name, 
                                 orders_detail.connection_fee, orders_detail.rental_fee, orders_detail.prorata_start, orders_detail.prorata_end, orders_detail.id as itemID 
                          FROM orders INNER JOIN orders_detail ON orders.id = orders_detail.order_id
                          WHERE orders.id = '$order_id' AND rental_fee >'0.00' ");
echo mysql_error();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results8a)) {
    $itemID = $row['itemID'];
    $itemRental = $row['rental_fee'];
    $itemConn = $row['connection_fee'];
    $install_date = $row['install_date'];

    //start prorata calculations = start date until the end of month

    $s_year = date("Y", strtotime($install_date));                       // get year number
    $s_monthname = date("F'", strtotime($install_date));                 // get month name
    $s_daytostart = date("d", strtotime($install_date));                 // get the day number

    $s_month = date("m", strtotime($s_monthname));                       // get this months number
    $s_daysinmonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $s_month, $s_year);// get days in this month
    $start_daysleft = $s_daysinmonth - $s_daytostart;                    // days left until the end of the month

    // prorata value = (monthlyrental / days in month) * days left

    $prorata_startservice = $itemRental / $s_daysinmonth;
    $prorata_startservice = $prorata_startservice * $start_daysleft;

    // update to fields
    mysql_query("UPDATE orders_detail SET prorata_start = ' $prorata_startservice'  WHERE id = '$order_id' AND id = '$itemID' ");
}
mysql_free_result($results8a);
```

Comment: *insert obligatory **dont use mysql driver its deprecated** message here*

Comment: plus 1 for the above. And where are you getting `$order_id` from ?

Comment: $order_id = $_GET['order_id'] taken from previous page.

Comment: sorry limited knowledge of php and am not sure what you means by 'obligatory'

Comment: I believe the problem is on this line: `WHERE id = '$order_id' AND id = '$itemID'` your `id` column will probably never be the same for `$order_id` and `$item_id`. Is that expected?

Comment: @DAVEO - That's fine, we're here to help. So I am assuming that in your table you have multiple rows with the same `$order_id` ?

Comment: @DAVEO are you still having the problem? Give us some feedback.

Comment: Yes the summary table has id and the detail table has order_id. The ID field seemed to be an issue with updating the multiple records as it is now working. unfortunately the calculations are now off where as before they update OK. I am using 19th as the install date which should give monthly cost = £69.95 divide by 29 days multiply by days left (10). i get £27.08 instead of £24.12. must have something mixed up here

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do the calculations all in one query in mysql - though it is not tested.

```
UPDATE `orders_detail` 
SET `prorata_start` =( ( `rental_fee` / day( last_day(`install_date`) ) ) * ( day( last_day(`install_date`) ) - day( now() ) ) ) 
where `id`='{$order_id}';
```

Comment: more understandable structure

orders
id | site_id | install_date | status | prorata_s | prorata_e | conn_paid


orders_detail table structure 
id | order_id | connection  | rental | prorata_start | prorata_end. 

prod 1 conn = 0.00 rental = 4.99  
prod 2 conn = 0.00 rental = 69.95
prod 2 conn = 69.95 rental = 0.00

Answer (score 0):

You are not supplying us with enough information. We would need to know how your `orders_detail` table is structured but I would have to assume with the information you gave us, the table is probably like this:

```
+----+---------+---------------+-------+-------+
| id | item_id | prorata_start | other | other |
+----+---------+---------------+-------+-------+
|    |         |               |       |       |
+----+---------+---------------+-------+-------+
```

With that assumption in mind, your `UPDATE` query is wrong because you are using `WHERE id = '$order_id' AND id = '$itemID'` which means that if `$order_id = 1` and `$item_id = 2` the update will never happen.

You most likely need to change it to something like:

```
 WHERE id = '$order_id' AND item_id = '$itemID'
```

However, do you really need `item_id` in your table? If this table tracks orders, you shouldnt need the `item_id` there, the order ID number should be sufficient, in that case your `WHERE` should only be:

```
 WHERE id = '$order_id'
```

Comment: +----+----------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| id | order_id | product  | connection| prorata_start | prorata_end |
+----+----------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| 1  |  1       |    Prod 1     |   0.00    |            |    |
+----+----------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| 2  |  1       |    Prod 2     |  69.95    |             |    |      
+----+----------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| 3  |  1       |    Prod 3     |  40.00    |             |    |

Comment: in that case it should be `WHERE order_id = '$order_id'`